# How can I read and modify DATABASES into an HTML file?

Tags: html, css, sql, database, web

I'm searching to write a site for my python application. The site would be able to read a local Database file (.db), and eventually modify it.
Is it possible? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `.db` file could be just about anything.  What application/program/database wrote the file?

Comment: It's just a database... Writed in SQL language, or not?  I'm pretty new in this world.

Comment: Not necessarily.  `.db` isn't some universal format.  Do you actually have such a file?  Or are you just using it as an example?

Comment: Yes, I have a database (written in SQL using sqllite3 module on python) in that format, but I don't think this is important. 
My question was: how can I retrieve informations saved on a database, and then put them into an html/css-written website?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Man, I know how to use sqllite3 on python, I only would know how to read an sql-written file (database) and then put its informations on a website.
Or simplier, how can I read a file in html language?

Comment: This still makes no sense.  Out of the two thousand questions I've answered, this is one of the most ambiguous.  Please update your question with a concrete and material answer.   Give an example of what's in the file, what you want to extract from or write to the file, etc.  Not in vague and notional terms that only your understand, with concrete examples added to your question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example